# Remove enclosing double quotes from a parameter passed to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am calling a batch file like this:

```
test.bat C:\
```

The `C:\` parameter is passed to a command within the batch file like this:

```
start program.bat "%1"
```

I am finding that `program.bat` is starting like this:

```
program.bat "C:\"
```

Is it possible to remove the enclosing quotation marks from the parameter so that `program.bat` receives `C:\` instead of `"C:\"`?

Comment: Why are you passing `"%1"` if you don't want the quotes?

Comment: @Mat I was under the impression you had to...

Comment: @James Yes, you *would* need to if the parameter contains one or more space characters. For example: `program.bat "C:\Program Files\"`.

Answer (score 3):

`%1` evaluates to the first parameter as-is. That is, if the parameter is enclosed in quotation marks, they will be preserved.

`%~1` strips the quotation marks before evaluating.

So, use `%~1` in `program.bat` where you need to use the value of the first parameter without quotation marks.